# Configuring Video streaming With Azure for streaming H 264?

Tags: silverlight, azure, video-streaming, cdn

We are planning to use Azure blob storage to host few H.264 videos and then stream it using Azure CDN, with a Silverlight client consuming the stream.

Would love to get some inputs on the key considerations, best practices etc.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps
http://blog.smarx.com/posts/smooth-streaming-with-windows-azure-blobs-and-cdn